# Blending multiple images while retaining the original colors

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What I want:
[Done using photoshop (multiply)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0pZp.png)

[blend() with alpha=0.5, also blending with the white image on which I pasted it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsZkF.png)
Any workaround for my problem? The original images can be anything, just gave a reference image

[Image A with a transparent background (0,255,255,255)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrX5I.png)

[Image B with a transparent bg (255,0,255,255)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P6l0.png)

Comment: You want to blend A and B to make C, but you didn't give us A and B. Please also show your code. Thank you.

Comment: I have added them now, thanks

Comment: Given images A and B are identical. Could you please correct that?

Comment: updated, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways to do it, but this should be quite generic and adaptable for other situations:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load both images and make into Numpy arrays
a=np.array(Image.open('A.png').convert('RGBA'))
b=np.array(Image.open('B.png').convert('RGBA'))

# Make masks of all opaque pixels in each image, i.e. alpha>0
mA = a[...,3] > 0
mB = b[...,3] > 0

# Make empty result image
res = np.zeros_like(a)
res[mA] = np.uint8([255,0,255,255])     # make all pixels from A magenta
res[mB] = np.uint8([0,255,255,255])     # make all pixels from B cyan
res[mA & mB] = np.uint8([0,0,255,255])  # make all pixels common to A and B blue

# Save result
Image.fromarray(res).show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is exactly what I was looking for